# NUnit: SetUp and TearDown for each test in a test fixture across multiple Fixtures

Tags: c#, nunit

I would like to have a generic SetUp and TearDown that is run with every test across multiple fixtures but all within a common namespace.  This would be something similar to the [SetUpFixture] attribute but would be run with every test.

I've tried using a base class with [SetUp] but resharper resolves this as inconclusive which isn't really ideal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't see any problem in using a base class with the generic code.

```cs
public class BaseTest 
{
    [SetUp] 
    public void SetUp()
    { 
        //Do generic Stuff 
    }

    [TearDown] 
    public void TearDown()
    {
        // Do generic stuff 
    }



[TestFixture]
public class TestClass : BaseTest
{
    [SetUp] 
    public void SetUp()
    { 
        //Do Stuff 
    }

    [TearDown] 
    public void TearDown()
    {
        // Do stuff 
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, my mistake had been having a [TestFixture] in the base class.